# How to put Header Inside the List view in android

Tags: android

How to create the Header Inside the Listview(First Row Is Fix which will not move verticaly when listview scroll verticaly) But This listview move Horizontaly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method of listview,

```
ListView l1 = new ListView(this);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Header");
l1.addHeaderView(tv);
```

You can use any View type object as Header

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you need is to separate the header from the view.

Comment: I have done same technique by using the Adapter but I have to scroll my column name and column data vertical and horizontal. If I separate my header and listview then in horizontal scrolling will give problem.